# Set Visual web part color according to the color of SP page?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, design

I have a visual webpart that shows white jQuery ListBox. When I change the look on my SP page the Web part is still white and looks ugly, I wonder if there's a way to make the Visual web part change its color according to the color of my page.

Comment: Use SharePoint inbuilt classes for same look as SP look..!!

Answer (score 1):

You can overload the inbuilt classes with you own CSS, and load that CSS in the Masterpage or in Site Settings, or anyway you can apply your own CSS.

Start with the [Chrome StyleBot plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en) to tinker with the existing CSS live in the browser.